# Как обнаружить, что клавиша не нажата

Tags: javascript, html, клавиатура

Нужно проверить по keyCode, нажата ли клавиша в данный момент, не используя keyup.
Я не прошу готового кода, но даже не представляю, в каком направлении двигаться.

P.S. keyup не использую потому, что он может иногда не срабатывать (например, при переключении вкладок)

Comment: Проверять нужно только одну клавишу? Если человек переключил вкладку(браузера) - то вы уже вообще ничего не узнаете, пока он не вернется на страницу.

Comment: а почему не использовать keyDown?

Comment: Объясню: у меня есть функция, которая совершает много разных действий, и одно из них- добавление клавиш в список нажатых, после отжатия, понятное дело, их нужно убирать

Comment: дело в том что если клавиша нажата то событие `keyDown` возникнет и будет повторяться как только перейдёте на вкладку со скриптом, может и устроит такой вариант. Подробности тут: еще будет установлен флаг `KeyboardEvent.repeat : true if a key has been depressed long enough to trigger key repetition, otherwise false` (http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#keydown)

Comment: Очень похоже https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/847517/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8