# Как сделать разовое действие при удержании кнопки?

Tags: javascript, клавиатура, javascript-events

Необходимо выполнить разовое действие при нажатии/удерживании пробела.

Переменная Player изначально имеет фон-1, если нажать кнопку space, то переменная Player изменит фон-1 на фон-2, а когда отпускаем, то будет фон-1. Здесь все ок. Проблема возникает, когда зажимаешь/удерживаешь кнопку space, тогда остается фон-2, а мне нужно, что было разовое действие, независимо от того отпустил ли я кнопку после нажатия или нет.

```
var Player = backgroundImage-1;

document.onkeydown = function (event){
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
        Player = backgroundImage-2;
    };

document.onkeyup = function(evt){
    if (evt.keyCode == 32) {
        Player = backgroundImage-1;
    };
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в решении данного вопроса

Answer (score 0):

```
var Player = backgroundImage-1;
var down = false;

document.onkeydown = function (event){
  if (!down) {
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
        Player = backgroundImage-2;
    };
    down = true;
  }
}

document.onkeyup = function(evt){
  if (down) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 32) {
        Player = backgroundImage-1;
    };
    down = false;
  }
}
```